# Rhomobile: Not able to post the update on twitter

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, rhomobile

I am using Rhomobile (for Android) to post status update on Twitter. For that, following the steps of Oauth implementation I am able to get logged in with Twitter but after login, when trying to post the status update everytime I got HTTP Response as `{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}`.

Below is the relevant code for making the request to post status update.

```
def post_to_twitter(comment)

    $rnd = rand(36**32).to_s(36)    
    $post_status_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"   
    $oauth_token1 = @account_set.tt_oauth_token
    $oauth_token_secret1 = @account_set.tt_oauth_token_secret

    @oauth_nonce = $rnd
    @oauth_timestamp = Time.now.to_i.to_s
    @http_port = System.get_property('rhodes_port')

    @url_param =  "oauth_consumer_key="+ $oauth_consumer_key + "&" +
                  "oauth_nonce=" + @oauth_nonce + "&" +
                  "oauth_signature_method=" + $oauth_signature_method + "&" +
                  "oauth_timestamp=" + @oauth_timestamp + "&" +
                  "oauth_token=" + $oauth_token1  + "&" +
                  "oauth_version="+ $oauth_version + "&" +
                  "status=" + Rho::RhoSupport.url_encode("Test") 

    $oauth_sign = get_auth_signature($post_status_url, @url_param, "")

    @auth_header = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key="+ $oauth_consumer_key + ", " +
                  "oauth_nonce=" + @oauth_nonce + ", " +
                  "oauth_signature=" + $oauth_sign + ", " +
                  "oauth_signature_method=" + $oauth_signature_method + ", " +
                  "oauth_timestamp=" + @oauth_timestamp + ", " +
                  "oauth_token=" + $oauth_token1  + ", " +
                  "oauth_version="+ $oauth_version + ", " +
                  "status=" + Rho::RhoSupport.url_encode("Test")

    postTTres = Rho::AsyncHttp.post(
      :url => $post_status_url,
      :headers =>{"Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Authorization" => @auth_header }
    )
    p postTTres 
end
```

The signature generation function is as follows:

```
def get_auth_signature (url, url_param, secret)
    signature = "POST&" + Rho::RhoSupport.url_encode(url).to_s +
    "&" + Rho::RhoSupport.url_encode(url_param).to_s

    key = $oauth_consumer_secret + "&" + secret
    hmac = HMAC::SHA1.new(key)
    hmac.update(signature)
    $signature = Base64.encode64("#{hmac.digest}")      
    $signature = Rho::RhoSupport.url_encode("#{$signature.gsub(/\n/,'')}")
    return $signature
end
```

The parameters values when traced are as follows:

@url_param before generating signature ---------

> oauth_consumer_key=2ChmEzWBe5Y9hMYODqA1IQ&oauth_non
>   ce=iyb9502vspjnhj9orb87sriych16678b&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1380117614&oauth_token=244586214-M6A2jMlR7vZiqwAMrfuSj7I7XFzFTRd4
>   6nV6aTLK&oauth_version=1.0&status=Test`

Passing `@url_param` to `get_auth_signature()` to generate signature.
Generated signature url and signature is

Signature string ----------

> POST&https%3A%2F%2Fapi.twitter.com%2F1.1%2Fstatuses%2Fupdate.
>   json&oauth_consumer_key%3D2ChmEzWBe5Y9hMYODqA1IQ%26oauth_nonce%3Diyb9502vspjnhj9orb87sriych16678b%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timesta
>   mp%3D1380117614%26oauth_token%3D244586214-M6A2jMlR7vZiqwAMrfuSj7I7XFzFTRd46nV6aTLK%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26status%3DTest"`

Base64 string -------

> gjdXuU3qoGNt90Q2dRhNM3IXaBI%3D

Passing all these values as header Authorization to https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json

and got

Http Response as `{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}`.

Also tried passing it as post parameters in :body but no luck.

```
postTTres = Rho::AsyncHttp.post(
   :url => $post_status_url,
   :headers =>{"Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}, 
   :body => @url_param + "&oauth_signature=" + $oauth_sign
)
```

Checked the system timings with Twitter server timings and thats fine.

Also tried with static oauth_token that we can get from Twitter account but then too same response.

Please help me to fix this. I am unable to trace what I am missing or where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- The "status" parameter is a normal post data parameter, should not be in the authorization header, see https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/post/statuses/update
- There is a strange issue with API 1.1, with encoding special chars (like %20 for " "). The following did it for me: url encode the content of "status" for the input of the signature and do not encode it in the post data itself.

EDIT:

You forgot to supply the secret that corresponds to the user_token:

```
$oauth_sign = get_auth_signature($post_status_url, @url_param, "")
```

When you gain an access token from Twitter via https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token , twitter replies with an auth_token and an auth_token_secret (and the id and screen_name). You correctly supplied the auth_token in the params (and thereby to the signature), but you should supply the auth_token_secret where you currently put "".

EDIT 2:

Above edit makes me wonder: did you gain an access token using https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token ? Because for that you should use the oauth_token_secret that is a parameter in a call from twitter to the callback url supplied to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token . This callback url is called as a response to confirmation of a user via https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize. For https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token you could use "" as a secret, since there is no auth_token yet in that phase (and thereby no corresponding secret).

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually, I have already tried 1st thing that you mentioned, but got same reply.

Comment: I have tried option 2 as you said only encoding status for the input of signature and removing encoding when passing in post body itself. Still same error message 'Could not authenticate you.' Anything else you want me to give it a try or anything I may be missing ?